# How to prove this special solution to generalized inverse of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am a student of measurement engineering and I often need to solve matrix equations with generalized inverse when processing measurement data.Maybe the generalized inverse I understand is not the same as the strictly defined generalized inverse,My tutor taught us a method of finding generalized inverse solutions, but I don’t know how to prove it strictly.

$A$ is an $N\times N$ singular matrix($A$ is not a full rank matrix), if $N\times N$ matrix $G$ satysfies $A=AGA$, we call $G$ the generalized inverse of $A$,denoted to be $A^-$

In actual application, we only require one special solution of $A^-$,，here is a special solution for generalized inverse of $N\times N$ matrix，for example，calculate the $A^-$ of
$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&0\\0&-1&1\\1&0&-1\\ \end{pmatrix}$,you can delete a certain row and column of $A$ and calculate the matrix inverse, and then fill the deleted rows and columns with "0", you will get $A^-$.

If you delete the first row and the first column of $A$,you have  $2\times 2$ matrix $A_1=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\0&-1\\ \end{pmatrix}$,$A_1^-=\begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\0&-1\\ \end{pmatrix}$,so we have  $A^-=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&-1&1\\0&0&-1\\ \end{pmatrix}$ which satysfies $A=AA^-A$.
You also can also delete the second row and the second column of $A$,and the third row or the third column of $A$.You will calculate a different $A^-$ which still satysfies $A=AA^-A$.

We suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ singular matrix，$rank$ of $A$ is $t$ and $t$ is less than  $n$,Two points need to be noticeed here.

1. we can delete $n-t$ rows and columns of $A$ to get at least one non-singular matrix,So this method is definitely effective
2. Only if when $t=2$ or $t=3$ this method is meaningful,because in this case we can easily calculate the inverse matrix.

I have not been exposed to the English version of the textbook, I hope you can understand my description.How to strictly prove that this method is correct?

Comment: See page 9 of [these](https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/guangliang.chen/Math253S20/lec6ginverse.pdf) lecture notes.

Comment: Check out Theorem 2.2 (and 2.1) [here](https://www.math.wustl.edu/~sawyer/handouts/GenrlInv.pdf) for a proof.